# Update state in a Kafka stream chain without using Kafka Streams in an EOS way

Tags: apache-kafka, process, stream, eos

I am currently working on the deployment of a distributed stream process chain using Kafka but not Kafka stream library. I've created a kind of node which can be executed and take as input a topic, process the obtained data and send it to an output topic. The node is a simple consumer/producer couple which is associated to a unique upstream partition. The producer is idempotent, the processing is done in a transaction context such as :

```
producer.initTransaction();
try
{
        producer.beginTransaction();

        //process

        producer.commitTransaction();
}
catch (KafkaException e)
{
        producer.abortTransaction();
}
```

I also used the `producer.sendoffsetstotransaction` method to ensure an atomic commit for the consumer. 
I would like to use a key-value store for keeping the state of my nodes (i was thinking about MapDB which looks simple to use).

But I wonder if I update my state inside the transaction with a `map.put(key, value)` for example, will the transaction ensure that the state will be updated exactly-once ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Kafka only promises exactly once for its components - i.e. When I produce X to output-topic, I will also commit X to input-topic. Either both succeeds or both fails - i.e. Atomic.

So whatever you do between consuming and producing is totally on you to ensure the exactly-once. UNLESS, you use the state-store provided by Kafka itself. That is available to you if you use Kafka-streams.

If you cannot switch to kafka streams, it is still possible to ensure exactly once yourself if you track kafka's offsets in mapDB and add sufficient checks.

For eg, assuming you are trying to do deduplication here,
[image]

This is just one way of doing things - assuming that whatever you put in mapDB is committed right away. Even if not, you can always consult the "source of truth" - which are the topics here - and reconstruct the lost data.